# checking wether webView is loading

Tags: macos, android-activity, webview

I want to check whether my webView is loading. my code is:

```
if (???) {
    [activityIndicator startAnimation:self];
} else {
    [activityIndicator stopAnimation:self];
}
```

I know for iOS its `webView.loading`. What is it for mac?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of starting the animation while the webview is loading, start the animation before you load the webview. Then stop the animation when the webview finishes loading

Comment: Is it WebViewDidFinishLaunching?

Comment: start the animation here : -(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView, end the animation here: -(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView, if you have problems with webViewDidFinishLoad not calling then see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935157/xcode-4-1-webuidelegate-mac-osx